# In the Nashorn JavaScript engine, how can I read a file from the file system?

Tags: require, filereader, nashorn

In the Nashorn JavaScript engine, how can I read a file from the file system? In node.js I use

```
fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync("sometext.txt")
```

but in Nashorn this gives already an exception on the `require` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

### 1 Use the Scripting API

The Nashorn engine can be started with the `-scripting` flag. Once you've done this, you can use the JS function `readFully` to read the content of a file into a variable.

Instantiate the Nashorn engine and use it as follows (Java code):

```
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(new String[] { "-scripting" });
        
engine.eval(new FileReader("myscript.js"));
```

where the JavaScript file contains:

```
...
var content = readFully("mytext.txt")
...
```

### 2 Use the Java API

Read the file in JavaScript via calls to the classes/functions in `java.nio.file` and then convert the resulting Java bytes object to JavaScript.

Instantiate the Nashorn engine in the normal manner (Java code):

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");
    
engine.eval(new FileReader("myscript.js"));
```

and put in the JavaScript file `myscript.js`:

```
var pathObj = java.nio.file.Paths.get("mytext.txt")
var bytesObj = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(pathObj);

var bytes = Java.from(bytesObj) // converting to JavaScript

var content = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes)
```